# Redmine Archlinux Apache Passenger

Tags: apache, passenger, redmine, archlinux

I currently try to setup redmine in Archlinux (VM) using the tutorial:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redmine

Redmine can be started using "ruby bin/rails server webrick -e production" (install test).

i have already run "passenger-install-apache2-module" and added the lines to "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf".

This is where the Arch tutorial ends.

I can also start it calling "passenger start" in the redmine directory, but i cant get appache loading it automatically.

For starting i currently have added:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
  DocumentRoot /ust/share/webapps/redmine/public
  <Directory /ust/share/webapps/redmine/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(This last part was a try from http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/setup-redmine-fedora-22/)

PS: i also tried to call the "ruby bin/rails server webrick -e production" line using systemctl (as describet at the end of arch) but this one only gets errors i cant understand.
PPS: Ther also is a Nginx (port 80) on the system, Apache is on 8080 (just in case that might interfere.)

---

EDIT: Trying to get Logs (i hope to grb the correct files):

/var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.5833 854/7fbcbe96dd00 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1281 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.6193 1081/7fd495dacd00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1070 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.6197 1081/7fd495dacd00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:245 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.6245 1081/7fd495dacd00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:820 ]: Passenger core online, PID 1081
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.6279 1088/7f56ce6b3d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.7834 1088/7f56ce6b3d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 1088

[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9048 1081/7fd483fff700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:585 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdo$

[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9049 1081/7fd495dacd00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:989 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9049 1088/7f56c8a30700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:422 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force s$
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9049 1088/7f56ce6b3d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:492 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnecte$
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9049 1088/7f56bbfff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9049 1088/7f56bbfff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9050 1081/7fd482f7c700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9050 1081/7fd482f7c700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9051 1081/7fd483fff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9051 1081/7fd483fff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9052 1081/7fd4837fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9052 1081/7fd4837fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9054 1088/7f56c8a30700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9055 1088/7f56ce6b3d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9055 1081/7fd4826fa700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:42.9055 1081/7fd4826fa700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0683 1127/7f64d2621d00 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1281 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0715 1130/7fa99d107d00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1070 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0716 1130/7fa99d107d00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:245 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0737 1130/7fa99d107d00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:820 ]: Passenger core online, PID 1130
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0772 1136/7f1a31534d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.0776 1136/7f1a31534d00 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 1136
[Mon Feb 06 23:16:43.078579 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 838:tid 139947678662592] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/5.1.2 configured -- resuming n$
[Mon Feb 06 23:16:43.078699 2017] [core:notice] [pid 838:tid 139947678662592] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:43.1472 1081/7fd495dacd00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1055 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ 2017-02-06 23:16:45.6587 1130/7fa997cae700 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:464 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

/var/log/httpd/access_log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:16:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 481
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:17:01 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1126
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:18:35 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 481
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:18:35 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 481
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:18:35 +0100] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2017:23:18:35 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1126
```

/usr/share/webapps/redmine/log dosent contain a file for 2017-02-06
(neither rubys log nor passenger?)

for "journalctl -S today -u httpd" i only get:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2016-09-17 11:12:13 CEST, end at Mon 2017-02-06 23:36:36 CET. --
Feb 06 23:16:42 arch-devel systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
```

---

Edit 2:

Moved  block to /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, and enable it in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
(Effectively the block was moved to before the "passenger" block, no other configuration was given in httpd.conf)

After the next restart ther were acces problems (Apache cant acces /usr), which were solved by changing httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
  DocumentRoot /usr/share/webapps/redmine/public
  <Directory /usr/share/webapps/redmine/public>
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/redmine_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: hope i fouind the relevant kog files.
I see some messages about shutdown (of passenger) but this is the log after a simple boot. (So i dont know where that one came from.)

Comment: see this link. it describes how to install Redmine with Passenger: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_with_Ruby-on-Rails_and_Apache2-Passenger

Comment: That link had some useful tips, although the file/folder names are different in Arch. 
The resulting changes are in "Edit 2".